# Android NestedScrollView not scrolling in the NestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

This is my xml layout. I didnt find where is my mistake.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#e3e1e1">

            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/baslik"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:background="#34302F"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_back"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/geri_button"/>


                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/baslik11"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#34302F"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_back"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                    android:gravity="right">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:src="@drawable/recodelogo"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buton_zemin"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/yeniButton"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/yeni_kayit" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/kaydetButton"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yeniButton"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/disket" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/silButton"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kaydetButton"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/cop_kovasi" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/digerSecenekButton"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/silButton"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/diger_button" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/solButonlar"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView16"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Cari Kod :" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edt_cari_kod"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/black"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/siparisNoTextView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Stok Kod :"/>

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edt_stok_kod"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                            />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sagButonlar"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/solButonlar"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/solButonlar"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textViewTarih"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Seri No :"/>

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edt_seri_no"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/black"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView15"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Saat :" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edt_saat"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                            android:inputType="time"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Tespit :"
                    android:id="@+id/textView17"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/background_material_dark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:id="@+id/edt_tespit"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Arıza"
                    android:id="@+id/btn_ariza"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:background="#2e2929" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Malzeme"
                    android:id="@+id/btn_malzeme"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:background="#2e2929" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Kontrol"
                    android:id="@+id/btn_kontrol"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:background="#2e2929" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Görev"
                    android:id="@+id/btn_gorevlist"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:background="#2e2929" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#f1722e"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_bakimtip" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Malzeme Ekle"
                        android:id="@+id/btn_malzeme_ekle"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:background="#2e2929"
                        android:layout_margin="3dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Arıza Ekle"
                        android:id="@+id/btn_ariza_ekle"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:background="#2e2929"
                        android:layout_margin="3dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Kontrol Ekle"
                        android:id="@+id/btn_kontrol_ekle"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:background="#2e2929"
                        android:layout_margin="3dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Görev Ekle"
                        android:id="@+id/btn_gorevekle"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:background="#2e2929"
                        android:layout_margin="3dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_viewmalzeme"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/rakamLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_basla"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="İŞLEM BAŞLADI"
                    android:background="#99BB1B"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_bitir"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="İŞLEM TAMAMLANDI"
                    android:background="#99BB1B"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And this is my java codes.

Here is where I am initialze my recyclerVier

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_viewmalzeme);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
    LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    mLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

And here where I am set my adapter.

```
   private void setMalzemeAdapter(List<teknikUniversalModel> malzemelists){

    mAdapter = new MalzemeListAdapter(malzemelists,this,getSettingValue());
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

also I tried put app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" inside RecylerView and Nestedscrollview but it didnt work. And I am Using 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' library.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, THATS ALOT OF VIEWS!!!

and second of all `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`only disables recycerview scrollability(if that makes sense, it dosent makes it expand nor anything else) so maybile ur problem is that whole problem fits within the screen (once again, dont count every single item of recyclerview in...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this : add

```
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
```

in the `NestedScrollView`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```